# DB2 Commit and Then Get Diagnostics

Tags: database, db2, commit

Say you have an update statement that updates 5 rows. So Get Diagnostics ROW_COUNT = 5. If you commit and then try to Get Diagnostics ROW_COUNT does it now = 0?

Comment: Have you tried it to see?  At first guess, there's two things it would likely be - 0, or the total number of rows changed/locked during the transaction (not just for the last statement).  Although... _why_ do you want the information for the `COMMIT`?

Comment: I can't check it myself because I don't have permissions to make changes to the database. The problem the stored procedure keeps returning 0 when it shouldn't. I noticed where the commit was and told them to change it after the Get diagnostics ROW_COUNT, but I was trying to find out if that was correct or not. This would be much easier if I could change it and check it myself.

Comment: You have a `COMMIT` _inside_ a stored procedure?  What's it scoped to - would it affect transactions **outside** the sp (if so, and this is intended behaviour, please document it)?  Also, you may want to post the relevant code here...